# "Error:" "Unsupported_grant_type" Using OAuth 2.0, Owin. Password Grant and Authorization Grant

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin

I'm building a Web API Application using **Framework** NOT Core. I have a user Authorization which is Login/Logout/Register User **Password Grant_Type**, using **Owin** and **OAuth2** **Password Grant_Type**.

To Access the NopCommerce protected resource I have to authorize my application using OAuth2, Authorization Grant_Type obtaining a token. [enter link description here][1]

The Problem is when I call the **/Token** endpoint using **Authorization Grant**. The moment NopCommerce API Redirects the user to callback url, I see the **"Error:" "Unsopported_grant_type"** message.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
// Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
```

And The Standard **ApplicationOauthProvider.cs** that comes with **Owin**.

How can i use the above /Token endpoint using OAuth2 **Authorization Grant_Type**?

Comment: Did you add grant type in your authentication service?

Comment: No i havent as you can see in the above code. Wich is responsible for authorization. But Also where do i add the garant type? In the GetAuthorizationUrl method?

Comment: You are using resource owner password flow, read the doc here https://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

Comment: I have now edited my question with a proper descripton of the problem, and a firm question.

Answer (score 0):

So a while back i found a solution to my own problem. I did not have had the time to post my answer earlier. Any way.

First i thought the problem was in RouteConfig.cs, but it seems that the Standard **ApplicationOauthProvider.cs** is **NOT** ready for Authorization Grant, but is for Password grant. So to use **multiple Grant-Types** or Flow(s) the best practice is creating **custom Startup Options**.

**In my Case i added the following:**

```
NopOAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/NopAuthorize"),
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/NopToken"),
                Provider = new NopOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
                //true only in development
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(NopOAuthOptions);
```

And then i created my custom provider like this:

```
public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
        {
            var endpointPath = new PathString("/NopAuthorize");

            if (context.Options.TokenEndpointPath == endpointPath)
            {
                context.MatchesAuthorizeEndpoint();
                Trace.WriteLine(context.OwinContext.Request.QueryString);
            }

            return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
        }
```

Ofcourse for security it is best to also configure:

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)

 public override Task ValidateAuthorizeRequest(OAuthValidateAuthorizeRequestContext context)'
```

Etc....

Microsoft has a great Documentation page dedicated to Owin Oauth2 Authorization Server.

[Microsoft Owin Oauth2 Authorization Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)